# i am getting error after hosting a project done in asp.net.error occur if a user idle for 15 minutes. I get the following error

Tags: asp.net

i am getting error after hosting a project done in asp.net.error occur if  a user idle for 15 minutes. I get the following error.

```
enter code here
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<configuration>
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Sent at 3:29 PM on Tuesday

Comment: And what happens if you do as the message says?

Comment: Please post your Global.asax file